# Is there funny term or an idiom for this

Tags: phrase-requests

To describe or criticize a person who is not capable of doing easy tasks but want to do a harder task, just because he sees some professional doing it??

Comment: Maybe ***delusional***

Comment: George, Hi and thanks for visiting EL&U. I've edited your question to change the tags to Expression-requests and phrase-requests as 'Expressions' is for asking about an expression you already know, not finding one to fit a meaning. Could you take a few minutes to look click 'view tag' and then 'learn More' and read the tag info fo for Phrase-requests and make sure that you include all the information it requires, including research you've done? That way you are more likely to get helpful answers. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You can't run before you can walk](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212463/synonymous-idiom-for-you-cant-run-before-you-can-walk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_eyes_bigger_than_one%27s_stomach)):

> **have eyes bigger than one's stomach**
>   2. (idiomatic) To want more than one can handle.
>
> - 2010, Veechi Curtis, Lynley Averis, Bookkeeping For Dummies, page 75:
>     When choosing software, don't have eyes bigger than your stomach. Rather, stick to whatever level of software you need, and no more.

Although it might be more immediately relevant to the issue of greed, the notion of *overestimating one's ability* can carry over idiomatically to the situation you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Punching above your (their) weight.

Comment: Hello, Seaya. Though this _might_ work, checking in the dictionaries leads one to suspect that success (in achieving more than might be forecast) is usually implied.  Zebrafish suggested this answer years ago, then deleted it. But they _did_ add a lot of linked and attributed references, always expected on ELU.